# SQL Statement based on several tables and conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

My Question is, if I have 2 tables and 3 conditions, at Table1 I have to check 2 conditions and at Table 2 I have to check only 1 condition but comparing another raw value from Table2 to Table1 as well.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM Table1 WHERE Column_name1 = 'condition1' or Column_name2 = 'Condition2';
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM Table2 WHERE Column_name3 IS NOT NULL;
```

So I'm trying to create 1 sql code out of this 2, so it will check both tables and return the values where at least one condition will be true. It should show the value of the CUSTOMER_ID table.

I have tried something like this

```
    SELECT CUSTOMER_ID 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Column_name1 = 'condition1' or Column_name2 = 'condition2'
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Column_name3 IS NOT NULL
WHERE Table1.CUSTOMER_ID=Table2.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

but I'm quite new in this field let's say and I don't really understand why is it not working.

The desired result should be if any of the conditions are true from any of the TABLES then it will return the CUSTOMER_ID but it might happen that one CUSTOMER got not only one as true but maybe all the conditions will be true, so I need to list the ID of the customer only once.

If I should give more clarification please let me know.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Look up 'union' in the documentation.

Comment: Your question is not completely clear to me.  Instead of _describing_ your problem in words, _show us_ sample table data and the expected output.

Comment: ON is for joining conditions, i.e. Table1.CUSTOMER_ID=Table2.CUSTOMER_ID. WHERE is for "filtering", e.g. NOT NULL-conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not very clear but it looks you need:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM Table1 
  WHERE Column_name1 = 'condition1' or Column_name2 = 'Condition2'
union
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID FROM Table2 
  WHERE Column_name3 IS NOT NULL;
```

`join` is used  when you need to create one result row from two (or more) source rows from different tables. 
`union` is used when you need to get sum of results of multiple queries. `union` will return only unique results when `union all` return all results.

Answer (score 0):

Go for this:

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID 
 FROM Table1 
 LEFT JOIN Table2
    On Table1.CUSTOMER_ID=Table2.CUSTOMER_ID;
 WHERE Column_name1 = 'condition1' or Column_name2 = 'Condition2' or Column_name3 IS NOT NULL
```